# How to Publish an WinForms into 1 executable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, msbuild, .net-4.8

I wanted to Publish a WinForm (.Net framework) as an executable (JUST 1 File). I had tested different ways of doing it.

I had tried

> dotnet publish -r win-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true --output ../result
>
> Error: C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.302\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3746,5):
> error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AL" task could not be loaded
> from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the
>  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
> dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
> that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
> [C:\RPIC\PICDashboard\PICDashboard\PICDashboard\PICDashboard.csproj]

and

> msbuild /t:Publish /p:PublishSingleFile=True /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=True /p:SelfContained=True /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64 /p:OutputPath=../result

msbuild works without error but it produces many files as what's in the Debug and Release folder. It also give me a warning

> C:\RPIC\PICDashboard\PICDashboard\PICDashboardSetup\PICDashboardSetup.vdproj.metaproj : warning MSB4078: The project file "PICDashboardSet
> up\PICDashboardSetup.vdproj" is not supported by MSBuild and cannot be built.

I had also tried

> dotnet msbuild -target:Publish -property:PublishSingleFile=True -property:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=True -property:SelfContained=True -property:Configuration=Release -property:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64 -property:Platform="Any CPU" -property:OutDir=../result
>
> Error: C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.302\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3746,5):
> error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.AL" task could not be loaded
> from the assembly Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core, Version=15.1.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.  Confirm that the
>  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its
> dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class
> that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.
> [C:\RPIC\PICDashboard\PICDashboard\PICDashboard\PICDashboard.csproj]

Is there any way that allows me to publish WinForms as a single exe?

Answer (score 1):

"Any way" - *yes*, though I can't say "always"/"for all" applications and its dependencies.

Also, the following is done in Visual Studio (not `dotnet` cli - I haven't tried) with a trivial "Hello World" Windows Forms app (*no external dependencies*)

1. In your Application Build properties -> **Release** Configuration set Debugging information to `None`
   [image]
2. In your `Publish Settings`
   [image]

Result (in the `bin\Release\net5.0-windows\publish\` folder set above):
[image]

Running an awesome app :)
[image]

Comment: I had changed the Build setting but for step 2 I am not getting the UI as your instead I just get a publish wizard which does not have all those options.

Comment: Same as @323Kobby. Visual Studio forces the creating of a Click Once installer.

Comment: For me, by changing the "Deployment Mode" under the final tab "Configuration" to "Self-contained", I revealed two additional options, "Produce Single File" and "Enable ReadyToRun Compilation."